# Many Fragments, Navigation Drawer on Smartphone / Tablet

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation

i'm plan a new app with the navigation drawer and have therefore 1-2 questions...

Google/Android says that the communications has to be done over the main activity (with callbacks) which holds the navigation drawer. I think this is possible with 4-6 fragments.

My app should work on phones and tablets and has at least 10-12 fragments and i think that the management over one Main Activity is to much, or isn't it?

So i want to implement more activities. How can i smoothly close the navigation drawer and start a new activity? Is this only possible with a delayed start?

Or does anybody know a better method to manage so many fragments and a navigation drawer on a phone and tablet?

PS: sorry... for my english ;)

Comment: 12 is not much i have 40+ fragments in my project. Using navigation drawer will force you to use fragments(multiple activiy after navigationdrawer is not a good practice). My suggestion is reuse fragments as much as possible and dont worry about the numbers

Comment: That means you have one MainActivity and 40+ callback functions? ;) 40+ interfaces or how do you handle that?

Comment: simple have 40 interfaces. Beside I liked working like that no more adding activity tag in manifest and worry about activity lifecycle. Imagine what would happen if I had 40+Activities